# ERRORS while building asterisk using meta-telephony layer

Tags: asterisk, yocto, openembedded

I am trying to build asterisk , I am using  meta-telephony layer provided from oe-layers.
I have faced few issued while building the application "asterisk" for raspberry pi 3 b.
Initially I have build core-image-minimal  for Rpi and it worked successfully.
Tried to build few applications like lighttpd, SQLite3 and they worked successfully.
Now i am trying to build an application called "asterisk" whose recipe is in meta-telephony -> recipe-asterisk-asterisk-asterisk_13.5.0.bb , but I have encountered few errors.
Need guidance for below Error i have faced

```
WARNING: Layer telephony should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_telephony in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
WARNING: Layer telephony should set LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_telephony in its conf/layer.conf file to list the core layer names it is compatible with.
Loading cache: 100% |###########################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 1370 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: ParseError at /home/bhavya/dialtronics/yocto/poky-dunfell/meta-telephony/classes/waf-samba.bbclass:4: Could not inherit file classes/pythonnative.bbclass
```

Please kindly help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance

bhavya

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the last commit on [meta-telephony](https://git.osmocom.org/meta-telephony/) was from 2017.  This is long before the Yocto release [Dunfell](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Releases) you would like to use.
Mixing meta-layers in different Yocto releases isn't something you do to have fun.

Or you try to find out what release they where using, and go back to these old days.  Or you pick up the work and try to maintain a more up to date meta layer.

And to start it, I thing the pythonnative.bbclass is now [python3native.bbclass](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/classes/python3native.bbclass?h=dunfell).  Note in Dunfell the Python2 support stopped (as in almost all distro?).

BTW: the version in the meta layer is also quite old (13.5.0).  Latest version seems to be [17.5.1](https://www.asterisk.org/downloads).

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks 
Initially, while I am trying with asterisk_13.5.0.bb I changed to python3native.bbclass then I faced a error with do_compile.then I have tried with asterisk_13.17.2.bb, asterisk_13.16.0.bb while compiling it I got an error saying that required neon dependency chain, while giving neon it been failed at do_fetch and I played with asterisk_13.17.2.bb and asterisk_13.16.0.bb but have not succeeded.

But when I tried asterisk_13.13.1.bb it worked like magic. no errors at all.
I have successfully build asterisk for raspberry pi.

Thank you soo much.~ 
~Bhavya

Comment: @Bhavya paruchuri You're welcome.  btw upvoting would be nice